# Dynamically load JS/CSS per template with Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

I understand a couple questions (i.e. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263232/how-to-conditionally-load-bundle-css-files-in-meteor-1-0)) of this nature have already been posted, however no solid solution has been found. From what it seems, Meteor currently lacks of the ability to dynamically load/render different UI JavaScript (i.e.  [uilang](http://uilang.com/)) or CSS files per template. In my application, I have templates that require specific JS libraries and CSS as oppose to other templates.

For example:

```
user.html requires -> uilang.js, user_ui_code.js, userstyle.css
admin.html requires -> uilang.js, admin_ui_code.js, admin_style.css
```

I would need each js/css file to render/load depending on which route gets requested (i.e. `example.com/user` or `example.com/admin`), for things like different background-colors, transitions, etc. Meteor documentation states:

> Files in /public are served to the client as-is. Use this to store assets such as images. For example, if you have an image located at /public/background.png, you can include it in your HTML with  or in your CSS with background-image: url(/background.png). Note that /public is not part of the image URL.

So you would think that putting all your js/css/images assets in public and calling the needed files statically in `head` would solve the problem. Instead, it seems that the JS (CSS as well) files get concatenated and it all runs at the same time regardless of which route you are on, thus overlapping code. I'm not sure if I am missing something blatantly obvious or is this an actual issue in Meteor?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not change the classes applied to you're body element when you want to change colors/background's etc?

Comment: We attempted that today. However, it only works to an extent. For example, uilang uses css classes on a certain section of the site to be activated. There is a ton of css and js code as well.

Comment: For example, the css linked on the home page gets applied to every page through out the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Meteor doesn't yet support lazy/on demand loading of resources.](https://github.com/MeteorCommunity/discussions/issues/27) The feature is on the roadmap as ["incremental loading"](https://trello.com/c/24s6vyxo/55-incremental-loading).

In the meantime, have a look at [numtel:publicsources](https://atmospherejs.com/numtel/publicsources) and [numtel:privatesources](https://atmospherejs.com/numtel/privatesources), which let you create bundles for lazy loading resources, with or without authentication.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for answering my question. I really do appreciate it.